# Which flaws does the following 2 out of 3 threshold secret sharing algorithm have?

Tags: secret-sharing

Let's say the secret is an ordered set of two 8-bit integers — $\{a, b\}$.

First, we generate additional entropy, another ordered set of random 8-bit integers — $\{c, d\}$.

\begin{gather}
a \oplus c = e\\
b \oplus d = f\\
c \oplus f = g\\
d \oplus e = h\\
\end{gather}
Using these equations we end up with three shards, ordered sets of two integers: $\{c, d\}$, $\{e, f\}$ and $\{g, h\}$. With any two of these, it would be possible to recover the original secret.

Are there any flaws in this algorithm? How secure is it given that a, b, c, d are all random?

Comment: Hint: Spell out the definition of $(g,h)$.

Comment: After thinking about it it looks like the entropy goes from 16 bits to just 8 for the third shard.